# formatting week.year in data frames to have starting zero in R

Tags: r, dataframe, lapply

I have a list of data frames where each data frame contains a date in the format week.year like 01.2019, 02.2019 and so on. I would like to retain the 0 in front of single digit weeks like 01 or 02 as right now it is changing it to 1,2 and so on. 
I have written the following code which works perfectly where the dataset$CAL column has the week.year values.

```
X <-list()
x <- nchar(dataset$CAL)
counter=1
for (i in x) {

  if (i==6){
    dataset$CAL[counter]<- paste0("0", dataset$CAL[counter])
  } 
  else {
    dataset$CAL[counter]<-dataset$CAL[counter]
  }
  counter <- counter+1
}
```

But this has a serious performance issue takes too long to load and also of course using for loop in R not recommended. 
I tried using lapply function  but it is not giving appropriate results

```
dataset$CAL <- lapply(dataset$CAL, function(x) if (nchar(dataset$CAL)==6) {paste0("0", dataset$CAL)} else {dataset$CAL})
```

Any pointers in this direction?? 
Really appreciate the Help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think `sprintf` would solve the problem :

```
dataset$CAL2 <- sprintf("%06s", dataset$CAL)
```

Or using `str_pad` from `stringr`.

```
dataset$CAL2 <- stringr::str_pad(dataset$CAL, 6, pad = "0")
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `sprintf` with `mutate`

```
library(dplyr)
dataset %>%
  mutate(CAL2 = sprintf("%06s", CAL))
```